# Jupyter: make files temporary to session

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Google Colab, everytime you have a new session all files except your notebook are deleted. If you have downloaded a `.zip` for example, it will only last as long as your session is active.

I am using Jupyter on my local machine and was looking for the same functionality, that everytime I enter a new notebook session, all files downloaded during the previous session are deleted.

Any why this could be possible.

Comment: One option on your local machine would be to run jupyter inside a docker container. If you don't save the new version of the container, the image it is associated with won't be updated. Next time you can launch a new container from your original image & be back at square one again. And if you hadn't said local, but like the temporary nature, you can use MyBinder launches from [these repositories](https://github.com/orgs/binder-examples/repositories?type=all) (look for the `launch binder badges in those links, for example the 'jupyterlab' one) or even your own once you add configuration files.

Comment: @Wayne Docker is always an option, but I was looking to see if there was some way to do this directly in a Anaconda environment.